# OAuth 2 Implemtation Not working as expected

Tags: angular, oauth, playframework-2.5

I am new to implementing the OAuth2 workflow. I am testing against google OAuth2 and my setup is as followed.

1. Play Framework for server side.
2. Angular 2 for client side.

Both applications are on the same box but are running under different ports. However, I have setup proxying for my client side ajax request.

The brunt of the work is done on the server side where I exchange a code issued by google for a token. Everything works when I manually test it and enter my authorization endpoint directly in a browser tab. I get redirected to google, login, and then redirected to the authorization endpoint and a token is then issued. When the authorization endpoint is first hit, it sends a 303 response and the browser automatically redirects to google. After a successful login, google redirects to my autorization endpoint with an access code in the url. The server reads the access code and sends it to google in exchange for a token. Lets say my authorization endpoint is http://localhost:8000/auth/google

However, when I try to initate the flow from my angular 2 application and send the code issued by google after a successful login to google. On the client side, I am initiating a request to google with a redirect_uri set to the authorization endpoint of http://localhost:8000/auth/google. After a successful login, I read the authorization code returned by google and send it to the server. In this instance, I get an error saying there is a redirect_uri_mismatch.

I can't understand why this setup would not work. Is google restricting an access code to a specific domain, meaning if my angular app is running on port 3000, is that access code only valid for requests coming from that port?

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I have spent hours trying to figure out why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the redirect_url in the console? Have you wait some time after registering it? Is it exactly the same?

see here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

> Your app must register with the system for the custom URI scheme in order to receive the authorization response. How your app registers its custom URI scheme varies by platform. Our libraries and samples demonstrate some platform-specific implementations of custom URI scheme redirects.

If you are dealing with authentication from the client side web-apps, you can also consider to use the implicit grant flow instead of authorization code that is more simple and designed to deal with the authentication on client side: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent